# Accessing another class

Tags: java

I've just started learning Java and this is the first thing I've written with it.
But I have problems getting into the concept of classes and thus I'm getting several errors.

I have two files; the first one is Book.java

If I try to compile the code I get 15 Errors, some of those because I return NULL where I am unable to do so. But I want to look for a solution for the other Errors first. All of them say 'cannot find symbol', because it apparently cannot access the other class.

Both of the files are in the same directory.
I've read that I have to create a Book class in the BookStore files main method and access it with that, but I don't know how to do that in this case.

I hope you can help me with my problem.

J.

Comment: for a start change `NULL` to `null`

Comment: For the `Book` class, name the constructor `Book`, not `makeBook`. In general, though, just go through each error message, think about what it's saying, and work out how to fix it. That's much better than asking us to rewrite your code so the errors go away, because that way you'll actually learn something.

Comment: Compiler errors should be something you figure out by reading the messages, referring to language sources to see where you went wrong, and fixing until you get a successful compile.  SO isn't the place to ask about compiler errors and lack of language knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, changed both. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things that i can instantly spot there,
1. `null` instead of `NULL`
2. You did not explicitly implement the constructor for Book.

When  you create a Book instance you need to use

```
Book book = new Book();
```

Note that the constructor has to be the same name as the class which is in this case "Book"
3. This is just a note and not something wrong, but take a look at the [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) data structure. Might help a lot instead of loops.

Comment: Thanks, I have already changed the NULL's to null's and renamed the constructor. Yet I still get the 'cannot find symbol' errors.

Comment: What i'm gonna say is for now and other times, you need to learn to use the debugger. Place a breakpoint and go through the statements one by one. You can see how your variables are changing and thus locate where the error exactly is. Finally, if you find this the correct answer, please don't forget to set as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

That Book class isn't the best choice.  Try this:

```
public class Book {
    private final String name;
    private final String isbn;
    private final double price;

    public Book(String name, String isbn, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.price = price; 
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("name: '%s' ISBN: %s price %10.2f", this.name, this.isbn, this.price);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 of your "main" method should be creating a "new" Bookstore, just like the line above it is doing. As for the first line of "main" though; you're creating a new book, and then never using it anywhere, so it can be removed.

This should remove at least 1 error and 1 warning from your list of errors. It would be helpful if you listed all the errors your compiler is giving though, so I'm not guessing.

Comment: Well I've changed the first two lines of the main method but nothing really changed.